# Kafka, Hostname verification by self signed certificate of OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, openssl

I am working on Kafka security using SSL(OpenSSL) everything is working fine except hostname verification
If I set `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` in any one side or both side(client and server)

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
```

then I am getting SSL handshake failed error
I searched a lot but getting only one answer that is

This error is due to the `SSL.endpoint.identification.algorithm` configuration option is set to HTTPS, enabling host-name verification, and is the default for Kafka 2.x clients. This needs to be set to an empty string to work or to restore to the previous version. like below

```
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
```

Please explain, Is host-name verification is possible with self signed certificate(CA) or else We need sign/verify it by recognized authorized CA(Verisign, GlobalSIgn which needs to pay)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?  I am specifically looking into the generic question you post at the end "Please explain, Is host-name verification is possible with self signed certificate(CA) or else We need sign/verify it by recognized authorized CA(Verisign, GlobalSIgn which needs to pay)"